# How to call Servlet from another Servlet page?

Tags: java, json

I have a servlet called X.java it writes out some data as JSON structure as the following :

```
{ "name":"JOHN" }
```

and I have another servlet called Y.java. It must call X.java and read the JSON structure of X servlet: in a variable k, and then Y should write out that variable k again like:

```
{ "name":"Hi John" }
```

How can I do that , without using Javascript 
I need to call the page X from page Y as :

Just use pure java. My code :

```
URL url = new URL( "myUrl/X");
HttpURLConnection connectionx = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connectionx.setRequestMethod("GET");
connectionx.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
connectionx.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
connectionx.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
InputStream myInput = connectionx.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(myInput));
String line;
String returnString = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    returnString += line;
}
```

---

the output is the first JSON : `{"name:": "John"}`
Thank you

Comment: Write it out to what?

Comment: Are you asking how to read a file? How to send an HTTP request?

Comment: it is not a file , it is just a page X.java that can be called by Y.java to read  the contents of X {JSON-structure} and display the result from Y.java..

Is that Possible ?? 
Or what You can Advice me ??

Comment: So you're asking how to call an ordinary function defined in a different class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess servlet X is mapped to some URL and the two servlets (X and Y) provide some sort of *service*... Why not using a common HTTP Client library from Y to call X?

Ps: sorry for all the "guessing", but can you provide a little more details?

Answer (score 0):

In Y servlet,  use request dispatcher to INCLUDE the X servlet. When you include X servlet,  use a custom HttpServletResponseWrapper to store Json return by servlet X.  That is it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
there are nine objects which are implicit objects in J2EE, one of them is session, what you can do is when X.java(1st servlet) does the processing and then put that result into session and then use `servletcontext.getRequestDispatcher().forward()` or servletcontext.getRequestDispatcher().redirect() to forward your request to Y.java. 
There are some differences in forward() and redirect method read them here

http://javapapers.com/jsp/difference-between-forward-and-sendredirect/

http://www.coderanch.com/t/365084/Servlets/java/whats-difference-redirect

and choose appropriate method for your use, I guess you need to use the forward() method.

Comment: I need to get JSON  by calling X-url in Y ,,

Answer (score 0):

All of these ideas, while perhaps workable, are insane.

Instead, put the routine your X servlet calls in to its own class and method, and simply invoke that. There's no reason to jump through the hurdles of the request dispatcher just to get your content. Refactor the core of the servlet in to a reusable component and invoke it directly, bypassing the whole HTTP and request infrastructure completely.

Comment: Since X and Y are the same servlet context so using Request dispatcher INCLUDE and custom HttpServletResponseWrapper is the best I think.